# what is the easiest way of differentating mobile & desktop version in sails.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

What's the best way to have a custom layout for users of mobile devices, under sails.js?

(other than loads of heavily conditioned .ejs files.)

Comment: [css media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) so css is applied based upon viewport size?

Comment: Any issues with the provided answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this:

- Detect devices via `express-device`, install via `npm install --save git://github.com/marionebl/express-device`
- Supply separate layouts for mobile devices

**Detect devices**

```
// config/express.js
var device = require('express-device');

module.exports.express = {
   // All your other express settings...
   middleware: {
     custom: true // This will not be needed on the next version of Sails
   },

   customMiddleware: function (app) {
     app.use(device(app).capture());
     app.enableDeviceHelpers();
     app.enableViewRouting();
   }
}
```

This will make `req.device` available, holding the device in `type`. `app.enableViewRouting()` opts into automatic routing based on the device type. Known types are `phone, tablet, desktop, tv, bot`
Documentation: https://www.npmjs.org/package/express-device

**Separate layouts based on device type**

To create a separate layout for a device type you can create a `layout.ejs` in `views/[type]/`. `express-device` will automatically pick up the special layouts for matching devices and render the default layout if no specific layout is found.

```
views/
 ├── view.ejs
 ├── layout.ejs
 └── [type]/
      └── layout.ejs
```

If `type = 'phone'` in this example, all requests from mobile phones will cause `res.view('view')` to use `views/phone/layout.ejs`. Any other device will get a response rendered with `views/layout.ejs.`